# How to encrypt existing database in android using GreenDAO library

Tags: android-sqlite, greendao

I am using GreenDAO library
I have facing SQL exception, after upgrade from older version to new
Example:
Version 1.0 : database is not encrypted
Version 2.0 : database is encrypted
existing users using 1.0 upgraded to 2.0
I getting exception after calling this,  before this I have to encrypt older database on upgrade. How to do this?

```
helper.getEncryptedWritableDb(password);



net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:84)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1820)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1785)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.keyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:2439)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabaseInternal(SQLiteDatabase.java:2368)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1041)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:249)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:214)
at org.greenrobot.greendao.database.DatabaseOpenHelper.getEncryptedWritableDb(DatabaseOpenHelper.java:134)
at org.broadsoft.iris.datamodel.db.DatabaseManager.openWritableDb(DatabaseManager.java:149)
at org.broadsoft.iris.datamodel.db.DatabaseManager.openReadableDb(DatabaseManager.java:129)
at org.broadsoft.iris.datamodel.db.DatabaseManager.getContactIdsInMessageHistory(DatabaseManager.java:461)
at org.broadsoft.iris.http.HttpManagerV2.lambda$fetchVCards$2(HttpManagerV2.java:573)
at org.broadsoft.iris.http.HttpManagerV2.access$lambda$2(HttpManagerV2.java)
at org.broadsoft.iris.http.HttpManagerV2$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "upgrade" from SQLite (unencrypted) to SQLCipher (encrypted). This is an outline how to do it:

1. Open SQLite DB
2. Open SQLCipher DB with different name to ensure a different DB file is used
3. Read data from SQLite
4. Write data to SQLCipher